# Python Error : (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for field clashes with reverse accessor for another field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Below is my models.py file in a Django project. 
Whenever I try to run the project I get the following error. Please assist as I have just started picking up django
I tried changing the names of the foreign columns as suggested by the error but no avail. A lot of answers out there suggest changes with respect to related_name which does not exist in my case.

Error from console

> app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor
>   for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code'.   HINT: Add or change a
>   related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item' or 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code'.
>   app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor
>   for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name'.   HINT: Add or change a
>   related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item' or 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name'.
>   app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code: (fields.E304) Reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item'.   HINT: Add or change a
>   related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code' or 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item'.
>   app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code: (fields.E304) Reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name'.  HINT: Add or change
>   a related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code' or
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name'.
>   app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name: (fields.E304) Reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item'.   HINT: Add or change a
>   related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name' or 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item'.
>   app_fin.TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name: (fields.E304) Reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code'.  HINT: Add or change
>   a related_name argument to the definition for
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_name' or
>   'TblLockerCoutCin.jewel_item_code'.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class TblJewelleryInventory(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    item_code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    base_locker_location = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_jewellery_inventory'


class TblJewelleryInventoryLogs(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    base_locker_location = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    triggered_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_jewellery_inventory_logs'


class TblLockerCoutCin(models.Model):
    jewel_item = models.ForeignKey(TblJewelleryInventory, models.DO_NOTHING)
    jewel_item_code = models.ForeignKey(TblJewelleryInventory, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='jewel_item_code')
    jewel_item_name = models.ForeignKey(TblJewelleryInventory, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='jewel_item_name')
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    is_check_out = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_check_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_locker_cout_cin'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `TblLockerCoutCin` model, both `jewel_item_code` and `jewel_item_name` fields have a many-to-one relationship with the `TblJewelleryInventory` model (specifically to the `pk` field). So, when an instance of `TblJewelleryInventory` would try to traverse the reverse relationship for any one of the fields, it would try to use `tbllockercoutcin_set` in both cases -- which would result in ambiguity as both reverse relations are referred by the same name.

In this case, you want to use a `related_name` argument and set different accessor names for the fields e.g.:

```
jewel_item_code = models.ForeignKey(
    TblJewelleryInventory,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    related_name='jewel_item_code',  # Here
    db_column='jewel_item_code',
)
jewel_item_name = models.ForeignKey(
    TblJewelleryInventory,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    related_name='jewel_item_name',  # Here
    db_column='jewel_item_name',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of the `related_name`...
Ex:

```
jewel_item_code = models.ForeignKey(
    TblJewelleryInventory,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    related_name='re_jewel_item_code',  # Here
    db_column='jewel_item_code',
)


jewel_item_name = models.ForeignKey(
    TblJewelleryInventory,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    related_name='re_jewel_item_name',  # Here
    db_column='jewel_item_name',
)
```

That's worked for me.